# Examples/Tutorials of Hunspell

Tags: spell-checking, hunspell

I've tried looking through the documentation found on SourceForge with Hunspell, but I'm still lost.  Are there any decent examples of hunspell that a C++ beginner would be able to follow?  Failing that, are there any free/opensource spellcheckers that are easier to use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree that their website is a little bit difficult to navigate and there aren't many tutorials for it.

I'd recommend just diving in.

For example here is some code for `NHunspell`, which is just the .net version.  The code below is just the basic usage but should still be useful for someone getting started.

You can download dictionaries from the `Open Office` [repository](http://extensions.openoffice.org/en/search?f%5B0%5D=field_project_tags:157)

```
//affPath = path to the .aff file
//dictPath = path to the .dic file

// create and load your hunspell object
NHunspell.Hunspell hunspell = new NHunspell.Hunspell(affPath, dicPath);

// want to add a word that is not part of the base dictionary? Sure, we can do that.
hunspell.Add("stackoverflow");

//lets check if a word is valid
bool isValid = hunpsell.Spell("stackoverflowed");
if(!isValid)
{
  //lets get some suggestions for this word
  List<String> suggestions = hunspell.Suggest("stackoverflowed");
  ...do stuff with your list of suggestions
}
```